# Video game RPG, fast travel via fairy flatulence

Tags: story-identification, video-games, rpg

I initially conflated this with [RPG where one of the party members has his powers enabled by making dolls](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/268124/rpg-where-one-of-the-party-members-has-his-powers-enabled-by-making-dolls-trans), but somewhere in the mid to late 1990s, I remember reading a review about an RPG, I'm pretty sure from Japan. The only salient detail I remember clearly is that one method of world movement (maybe the only one?) involved fairy flatulence. So instead of [being launched via a cannon](https://www.ign.com/wikis/doom-eternal/How_to_Fast_Travel_in_Doom_Eternal), or [drinking until they black out and wake up somewhere else](https://sunsetoverdrive.fandom.com/wiki/Fast_Travel), the characters make a deal with a fairy, who launches them to their destination. I think I remember a screenshot with the fairy's dialogue and then the sound effect, with the review mentioning it as being a bizarre choice. In retrospect, this might be one of those "Woolseyism" things where the translator couldn't find a way to translate the original text and instead made something up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is apparently *Vay* (found via [TvTropes](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/VideoGame/Vay) by search on Fartillery), which was an RPG on the Sega CD system published by Working Designs.

Working Designs was well known for inserting humor into their JPRG translations, quite often low-brow humor.  Many times this was to make the characters more relatable to American audiences, as opposed to translations which stuck too closely to the Japanese script.  In this case, the wind fairy Sufira controlled the winds to travel the party from point to point.  In the English translation, this became curse born fairy flatulence, which the party needed a gas mask to survive.

Comment: Despite being a fan of WD back in the day, and following them from the Lunar games until their demise, even this raises some question marks as to what they were on. (I missed Vay, was quite surprised when I found it)